# Attributes of an entity not available in LINQ to Entities

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Here is my problem with simplified example.

I have two entities modeled from SQL Server database:

1. Orders (columns available = OrderID, PackageCount,ManufactureDate, ShipDate, StatusID) Primary Key = OrderID)
2. OrderRecipients (columns available = RecipientID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Zip, Country, OrderID; Foreign Key = OrderID)

There is a [1 to many] relationship between Orders and OrderRecipients. One order can have several recipients.

I'm trying to extract the recipients of orders via the following code.

```
  var allmyrecipients = from o in mycontext.Orders
                        where (o.SiteID.Equals("NYC") || o.SiteID.Equals("SFO"))
                        select o.OrderRecipients;
```

However when I try to get the names of the recipients with the following code:

```
 foreach (var recipient in allmyrecipients)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(recipient.FirstName);
 }
```

the FirstName and other attributes of the recipient are not available in the Intellisense drop-down. I get "does not contain a definition of FirstName" error.

Why is this and what is the remedy? What am I doing wrong here?  I'm working with VS 2010, Entity Framework 4.

Thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: UPDATE1: I tried this bit of code and it doesn't throw an error :` foreach (var recipient in allmyrecipients) { foreach(var r in recipient) { Console.WriteLine(r.Name); } }` Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  I refactored this into somthing that should work using [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx).  Give this a shot:

```
var orders = from o in mycontext.Orders
    where (o.SiteID.Equals("NYC") || o.SiteID.Equals("SFO"))
    select o;

foreach (var recipient in orders.SelectMany(r => r.OrderRecipients)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(recipient.FirstName); 
}
```

Comment: with that, I get the following error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<MyNamespace.OrderRecipient>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyNamespace.OrderRecipient>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Corrected and refactored. I believe the SelectMany should handle the projection correctly.

Comment: Your response pointed me to the right direction. The LINQ query actually returns many orders, each of them having many recipients. That's why it threw the Conversion error. Thank you very much.